# abstract method error while creating bean to connect to Couchbase

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I am trying to connect to couchbase server using spring data couchbase. but i get a java.lang.AbstractMethodError.

my config.xml for connectino xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:couchbase="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/couchbase"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/couchbase
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/couchbase/spring-couchbase.xsd">

<couchbase:cluster>
    <couchbase:node>127.0.0.1</couchbase:node>
</couchbase:cluster>

<couchbase:clusterInfo login="admin"
    password="password" />

<beans:bean id="couchbaseEnv"
    class="com.couchbase.client.java.env.DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment"
    factory-method="create" />
<beans:bean id="myCustomTranslationService" class="org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.translation.JacksonTranslationService" />
<couchbase:env id="couchbaseEnv" connectTimeout="10000" />
<couchbase:indexManager />
<couchbase:repositories base-package="org.example.couchbase" />
<couchbase:bucket bucketName="bucket" 
    bucketPassword="password" /> 
</beans:beans>
```

my pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>${cglib.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- SPRING -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.17.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
<version>4.3.17.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
<version>4.3.17.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.17.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.17.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- CGLIB is required to process @Configuration classes -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Servlet API and JSTL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.17.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
<version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>



<dependency>
<groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
<artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
<version>11.2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.17.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.8</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
<groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
<artifactId>gson</artifactId>
<version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-data-couchbase</artifactId>
<version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

There are a lot of unused dependencies as i have been trying a lot of combinations and also implemented the same code to work on oracle sql database

the stack trace

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataRepository': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataRepository': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:742)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
at com.ibm.jpa.poc.App.main(App.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:99)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1284)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
... 11 more
```

my class

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface DataRepository extends CrudRepository<Payload,PayloadIdentity> {

}
```

and using this via

```
    @Autowired
    private DataRepository dataRepository;
```

I am using CouchBase Enterprise Edition 5.5.2

Comment: Are there any specific reasons why you chose XML mapping over annotations? Checkout this article https://blog.couchbase.com/couchbase-spring-boot-spring-data/

Comment: this is not a spring boot application and as I am starting from scratch I was unable to configure the environment from scratch. I kept getting an invalid password error even when I had entered the right password.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#dependencies.spring-framework: *The current version of Spring Data modules require Spring Framework in version 5.0.4.RELEASE or better*. You're using 4.3.17.

Comment: Can you suggest which version is compatible with spring 4.3.17